# SAP Hybris commerce production using spartacus

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce, spartacus-storefront

This is my first time developing with Spartacus. If i want to have it for production environment and not use recipes, how should i do this?
should i have a new accelerator and have a Spartacus storefront?
if not.. how will i be able to change in checkout service or facades or all this will be done in the storefront?
I checked the Spartacus documentation and all is using recipe
used recipes to generate the storefront and use it in a new deployment
tried making accelerator storefront based extension and changed the storefront to the new Spartacus
finally i used yacceleratorstorefront to generate extension. but not sure if i should update all the facade and model related stuff in this extension

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recipes have always been a shortcut to an initial demo setup of SAP Commerce, or just a starting point for your own developments.  They tend to include more addons and extensions than you may need in your project.  Also they directly include template extensions like yacceleratorstorefront and ycommercewebservices, which you should never do in production code.

To create your own project you should use ant extgen / ant modulegen as required to create your own extensions from the templates.  You should also review all extensions and addons included by the recipe, and remove those that you do not need.

For Spartacus you do not need the full accelerator storefront, but will likely need services and facades extensions for any custom features you create.  You will need the OCC webservices though: in 1905 and below that means creating your own version of ycommercewebservices & using occaddons, in 2005 onwards you can use commercewebservices (non-template) and occ extensions (i.e. not addons).

Essentially, you follow much the same process as you would have done for any other SAP Commerce or hybris project in the past.  The bit that differs is what extensions you include.

The reason all documentation references recipes is because otherwise it would be a very long-winded and error-prone series of steps to get an initial system up-and-running.

Equally, the Spartacussampledataaddon is just a starting point & as with all SAP Commerce project, you should create and maintain your own data extensions based on project requirements

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil. Will do so